# What do you use for base case for Int -> Int -> [Int] in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Say for example you have

```
InttoIntList x y
```

And its Type conversion was

```
Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

How would you establish a base case for two inputs to another list type like `[Int]`

Comment: Well that is not really depending on the type of the function itself, but on the *semantics* of the function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you mean by semantics of the function?

Comment: well the task the function is supposed to do. `Int -> Int -> [Int]` says what kind of input the function expects, and what the output type is. But there can be an infinite number of different functions with this type.

Comment: For example the type could also mean that you have two integers, `n` and `x`, and that you construct a list of `x`'s that has length `n`.

Comment: Would one way be defining new functions and then call them within a single function within InttoIntList?

Comment: So I have hard time thinking in the abstract when it comes to things like these.  Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base case is not determined by the type of the function. Yes frequently the type can give a hint. For example for a list, a base case is typically the empty list `[]`, but *not per se*.

Furthermore it is a common misconception that functions take two or more parameters. In Haskell, every function takes *exactly* one parameter. It is however possible that the output is a function that again takes a parameter (which is the case here).

With thes two issues solved, the question arises what the *base case* for `InttoIntList` is. Well a base case is a case with no recursion involved. If I understand your function correctly, you want to generate a list of numbers that each time increment from the first `Int` to the second `Int`.

So a base case could be the case where the first `Int` is greater than the second `Int`. In that case, we probably would want to return an empty list, so:

```
intToIntList m n | m > n = []  -- base case
```

and then the recursive case is when `m <= n`. In that case we typically would want to return a list that starts with `m` followed by the list that arises from `intToIntList (m+1) n`, so:

```
                 | otherwise = m : intToInt (m+1) n
```

Here `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` is a list constructor. It creates a list with `m` the *head* (first element) and `intToInt (m+1) n` the *tail* (remaining elements).

or putting it together:

```
intToIntList :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
intToIntList m n | m >= n = []
                 | otherwise = m : intToIntList (m+1) n
```

Comment: Thank you.  What exactly did you do with the otherwise.  What did you exactly do with m with the con :